# How can I write a query using ElasticSearch similar to SQL "Like" Operator?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to convert following query to an Elasticsearch query.

```
Select * from Books where title like '%net%'
```

Comment: Try this http://pastebin.com/jCgr5hCC

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173988/emulate-a-sql-like-search-with-elasticsearch

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791075/in-elasticsearch-how-do-i-search-for-an-arbitrary-substring

Answer (score 1):

Try [regexp query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html).

```
POST <index>/<type>/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "title": ".*net.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this gives an error... is there any way to do this using "match"

Comment: Can you please give more information about the error?